# $X $ and $Y$ are continuous $RVs$, such that$ f(x,y) = 2, 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq x+y\leq 1$

Tags: probability, random-variables, problem-solving

X and Y are continuous RVs, such that $f(x,y)  =  2, 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq x+y\leq 1$

I'm trying to find $P(x<1/2,y>1/2)$. So i'm integrating from $\dfrac{1}{2}$ to $1$ for $y$ and $0$ to $\dfrac{1}{2}$ for $x$ on $2\mathrm dx \mathrm dy$. But I'm still not getting the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure $f(x,y)=2$?

Comment: Yeah I am sure f(x,y) = 2.

Comment: You have not considered the additional constraint of: $0\leq x+y\leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows why it is important to keep track of when the pdf is zero. Using indicator functions, the pdf of $(X,Y)$ can be written as
$$
f(x,y)=2\mathbf{1}_{0\leq x\leq 1}\mathbf{1}_{0\leq y\leq 1-x}
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align}
P(X<\tfrac12,Y>\tfrac12)&=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)\mathbf{1}_{x<1/2}\mathbf{1}_{y>1/2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\
&=2\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{0\leq x<1/2}\mathbf{1}_{1/2<y\leq 1-x}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\
&=2\int_0^{1/2}\int_{1/2}^{1-x} \mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\\
\end{align}
$$
showing that the upper limit of the innermost integral should be $1-x$ and not $1$.

Comment: What if it was P(x+y < 1/4)? Also, I tried the integral what you did but I'm not getting the correct solution.

Comment: What did you get, and what is the correct solution?

Comment: 0.25 is the correct solution

Comment: Try recalculating the integral until you get 0.25.

Comment: I forgot the 2 outside, sorry about that. Thanks!

Comment: If I wanted P(x+y < 1/4) that's just one integral right, I can just treat x+y as a single variable?

Comment: That requires you know the distribution of $X+Y$. This is of course one way to go, another is to express the probability in terms of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and calculate it using the joint density.

Comment: We know its from 0<= x+y <= 1.

Comment: What is? ${{}}$

Comment: we know x+y is from  0<= x+y <= 1.

Comment: We know that the _joint density_ is zero unless $0\leq x+y\leq 1$, yes. And so what?

Comment: How do we go about solving for P(x+y < 1/4)?

Comment: Let $A=\{(x,y)\mid y<1/4-x\}$, then $P(X+Y<1/4)=P((X,Y)\in A)=\iint_A f(x,y) dx dy$.

Comment: What's the bounds on y and x when integrating?

Comment: Should be $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1/4-x} dy dx$ if I'm not mistaken.